# Is there any function by which we can access the specific value from specific cell (excel) from Python (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, function

I have data in the excel file. So I want to add a three columns in python and add values which are - ["exam ID" :   EXAM-001
"Subject" :    Maths
"Date" : 30-07-2022]

I have hundreds of excel file and I don't want to hard code. I just want that the function/the code which directly access the value from the cell address of the excel file and display the output in the python.

I have also mentioned the expected result below -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo9Vi.png)

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of libraries.
I use openpyxl.
Here you should be able to open the workbook, find specific cells wither by ID or by value, can add new cells, append.

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Examples : https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/python-openpyxl-tutorial/